# New size for MUI Radio button show warning

Tags: material-ui

By default, MUI Radio has two sizes, medium and small. I'm trying to create a new size (large) so I created this theme:

```js
import { RadioProps, Components, Theme } from "@mui/material";

import { pxToRem } from "../util";

declare module "@mui/material/Radio" {
    interface RadioPropsSizeOverrides {
        large: true;
    }
}

export const radio = (theme: Theme) => {
    const rootStyles = (ownerState: RadioProps) => {
        const sizeSmall = ownerState.size === "small";
        const sizeMedium = ownerState.size === "medium";
        const sizeLarge = ownerState.size === "large";

        const defaultStyle = {
            "&.Mui-checked .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                color: theme.palette.primary.main
            },
            ...(sizeSmall && {
                width: pxToRem(32),
                height: pxToRem(32)
            }),
            ...(sizeMedium && {
                width: pxToRem(40),
                height: pxToRem(40)
            }),
            ...(sizeLarge && {
                width: pxToRem(44),
                height: pxToRem(44)
            })
        };

        return defaultStyle;
    };
    return {
        MuiRadio: {
            defaultProps: {
                color: "primary"
            },
            styleOverrides: {
                root: ({ ownerState }: { ownerState: RadioProps }) => rootStyles(ownerState)
            }
        } as Components["MuiRadio"]
    };
};
```

But I got this warning in the developer console:

```
react.development.js:209 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `fontSize` of value `large` supplied to `RadioButtonIcon`, expected one of ["small","medium"].
```

And it seems it's because of [this example.](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Radio/RadioButtonIcon.js#L69C3-L69C50)

Is there any workaround?